# ConnectionRefusedError returned when using FastAPI on Different devices

Tags: python, fastapi

At the moment, i have two python files communicating through FastAPI, client.py and main.py. Client.py should pass a image file and some variables to main.py. When both files are run on the same Raspberry Pi 4B, the programs work perfectly well. If i try and access http://127.0.0.1/docs on a different computer, an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error pops up. if main.py is ran on the raspi and client.py is run on a different computer (or the other way round), client.py returns the error: `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`
I am not using Docker and all python versions are at minimum 3.9

Main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form

app = FastAPI() 

path = 'MAIN'
@app.post("/"+path) 
async def API(file: UploadFile,mode: int,text):
    try:
        print(text)
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f: 
            f.write(contents) 
    except Exception: 
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"} 
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        if mode == 1:
            main(file,text,False)
    return {"message": f"Successfully uploaded {file.filename,mode}{text}"}
```

client.py

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MAIN'

text = 'Example Text'
mode = 1 
path = f"?mode={mode}&text={text}"
url = url+path

file = {'file': open('img.png', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=file)
print(resp.json())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a special address that always refers to the local machine.  If the server is on a different machine, then you will need to replace that with the actual IP address of the other machine.